# Facebook user to Parse.com

Tags: android, facebook, parse-platform, facebook-login

How do I get the data from The Facebook user to Parse.com? The code that I will provide below makes a user but it doesn't update it with data when I login, why is it not working?

```
public class LoginActivity extends Activity {

private EditText usernameView;
private EditText passwordView;



@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_login);


    LoginButton loginButton = (LoginButton)findViewById(R.id.login_button);
    loginButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

            onLoginButtonClicked();
        }
    });



    // Set up the login form.
    usernameView = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.etUsername);
    passwordView = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.etPassword);

    // Set up the submit button click handler
    findViewById(R.id.ibLogin).setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View view) {

            onNormalLoginButton();
        }
    });
}

@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

    ParseFacebookUtils.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
}


private void onNormalLoginButton(){
    // Validate the log in data
    boolean validationError = false;
    StringBuilder validationErrorMessage =
            new StringBuilder(getResources().getString(R.string.error_intro)); //please

    if (isEmpty(usernameView)) {
        validationError = true;
        validationErrorMessage.append(getResources().getString(R.string.error_blank_username));//enter username
    }

    if (isEmpty(passwordView)) {
        if (validationError) {
            validationErrorMessage.append(getResources().getString(R.string.error_join));// and
        }
        validationError = true;
        validationErrorMessage.append(getResources().getString(R.string.error_blank_password));//enter password
    }
    validationErrorMessage.append(getResources().getString(R.string.error_end));// .

    // If there is a validation error, display the error
    if (validationError) {
        Toast.makeText(LoginActivity.this, validationErrorMessage.toString(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG) //LENGHT_LONG means how long the message will stand
                .show();
        return;
    }
    // Set up a progress dialog
    final ProgressDialog dlg = new ProgressDialog(LoginActivity.this);
    dlg.setTitle("Please wait.");
    dlg.setMessage("Logging in.  Please wait.");
    dlg.show();
    // Call the Parse login method
    ParseUser.logInInBackground(usernameView.getText().toString(), passwordView.getText()
            .toString(), new LogInCallback() {


        public void done(ParseUser user, ParseException e) {
            dlg.dismiss();
            if (e != null) {
                // Show the error message
                Toast.makeText(LoginActivity.this, e.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            } else {
                // Start an intent for the dispatch activity
                ParseUser userguy=ParseUser.getCurrentUser();
                boolean validated=userguy.getBoolean("emailVerified");

                if(validated)

                {

                    ParseInstallation installation = ParseInstallation.getCurrentInstallation();
                    installation.put("user", userguy.getObjectId());
                    installation.put("fullname",userguy.getString("fullname"));
                    installation.saveInBackground();
                    openMainActivity();
                }else{
                    Toast.makeText(LoginActivity.this, "You need to confirm your Email!",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                }

            }
        }
    });
}


private void onLoginButtonClicked() {
    List<String> permissions = Arrays.asList("email", "user_about_me");
    ParseFacebookUtils.logInWithReadPermissionsInBackground(this, permissions, new LogInCallback() {
        @Override
        public void done(ParseUser user, ParseException err) {
            if (user == null) {
                Log.d("MyApp", "Uh oh. The user cancelled the Facebook login.");
            } else if (user.isNew()) {
                Profile profile = Profile.getCurrentProfile();
                user.put("gender", "");
                user.put("location", "");
                user.put("age", "");
                user.put("meet", "");
                user.put("status", "");
                user.put("link", "");
                user.put("fullname", profile.getName());
                user.setEmail("");
                user.signUpInBackground();
                ParseInstallation installation = ParseInstallation.getCurrentInstallation();
                installation.put("user", user.getObjectId());
                installation.put("fullname", user.getString("fullname"));
                installation.saveInBackground();
                openMainActivity();
            } else {
                Log.d("MyApp", "User logged in through Facebook!");
                ParseInstallation installation = ParseInstallation.getCurrentInstallation();
                installation.put("user", user.getObjectId());
                installation.put("fullname", user.getString("fullname"));
                installation.saveInBackground();
                openMainActivity();

            }
        }
    });

}


private void openMainActivity(){
    Intent intent = new Intent(LoginActivity.this, DispatchActivity.class);
    intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
    startActivity(intent);
}

private boolean isEmpty(EditText etText) {
    if (etText.getText().toString().trim().length() > 0) {
        return false;
    } else {
        return true;
    }
}


public void signUp(View view) {
    Intent intent = new Intent(LoginActivity.this, RegisterActivity.class);
    intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
    startActivity(intent);
}
}
```

Ignore the `onNormalLoginButton()` it works, `onloginButtonClicked()` is the problem.

Edit:
I've tried this but it also didn't work.

```
user.saveInBackground(new SaveCallback() {
                    @Override
                    public void done(ParseException e) {
                        if(e!=null){
                            Toast.makeText(LoginActivity.this,"User data didn't save!",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        }else{
                        openMainActivity();}
                    }
                });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Look at below code. Why do you call user.signUpInBackground(); again?
I think it should be **user.saveInBackground();**
**Also, please check the data type of your fields to make sure you put correct data type (Example: int/float/double for Number)**

```html
else if (user.isNew()) {
                Profile profile = Profile.getCurrentProfile();
                user.put("gender", "");
                user.put("location", "");
                user.put("age", "");
                user.put("meet", "");
                user.put("status", "");
                user.put("link", "");
                user.put("fullname", profile.getName());
                user.setEmail("");
                user.signUpInBackground();
                ParseInstallation installation = ParseInstallation.getCurrentInstallation();
                installation.put("user", user.getObjectId());
                installation.put("fullname", user.getString("fullname"));
                installation.saveInBackground();
                openMainActivity();
            }
```

From parse document, user.isNew() -> User signed up and logged in through Facebook!

```html
ParseFacebookUtils.logInWithReadPermissionsInBackground(this, permissions, new LogInCallback() {
  @Override
  public void done(ParseUser user, ParseException err) {
    if (user == null) {
      Log.d("MyApp", "Uh oh. The user cancelled the Facebook login.");
    } else if (user.isNew()) {
      Log.d("MyApp", "User signed up and logged in through Facebook!");
    } else {
      Log.d("MyApp", "User logged in through Facebook!");
    }
  }
});
```

If it doesn't work, try below code to know if your user is saved successfully or not

```html
user.saveInBackground(new SaveCallback() { 
  @Override public void done(ParseException e) { 
    if (e != null) { 
      Log.e("Exception", e.getMessage()); 
      return; 
  } 
  Log.e("OK", "Saved!"); 
}});
```

Comment: Yeah i just tried doing that and it didn't succeed. I tried this to see if maybe it was transitioning to the next activity too fast so it didn't have time to update or something. But that doesn't seem to be the case.

Comment: What is the exception you got?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/80722/discussion-between-phuc-tran-and-ivan-javorovic).