# Using parses Facebook login api, results in current user null

Tags: javascript, express, parse-platform, facebook-javascript-sdk, facebook-login

I am using parse to crate a simple demo site that allows users to login/signup using their Facebook account.

the login returns success, i also get correct user name
i also see the database get populated with the facebook acount data

but back at app.js: `Parse.User.current()` is **null**

**Jvascript on client side (index.html)**

```
    <script>
 // Initialize Parse
  Parse.initialize("zzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzz", "zzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzz");

  window.fbAsyncInit = function() {
      Parse.FacebookUtils.init({ // this line replaces FB.init({
        appId      : 'zzzzzzzzzzzzzzz', // Facebook App ID
        status     : true,  // check Facebook Login status
        cookie     : true,  // enable cookies to allow Parse to access the session
        xfbml      : true,  // initialize Facebook social plugins on the page
        version    : 'v2.3' // point to the latest Facebook Graph API version
      });
    // Run code after the Facebook SDK is loaded.
  };

    (function(d, s, id){
      var js, fjs = d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0];
      if (d.getElementById(id)) {return;}
      js = d.createElement(s); js.id = id;
      js.src = "//connect.facebook.net/en_US/sdk.js";
      fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js, fjs);
    }(document, 'script', 'facebook-jssdk'));

    function myFacebookLogin() {
     Parse.FacebookUtils.logIn('user_friends', {
        success: function(user) {
            if (!user.existed()) {
                alert("User signed up and logged in through Facebook!");
            } else {
                alert("Already logged on");
            }
            console.log(user);
            alert("user "+user);


            FB.api('/me', function(response) 
            { 
                $("#userIdInput").val(user.id);
                $("#userNameInput").val(response.name);
                $("#fb-login-form").submit();
            }); 
        },
        error: function(user, error) {
            alert("User cancelled the Facebook login or did not fully authorize.");
        }
     });
    }

    $( document ).ready(function() {
        $("#logon-block").click(function(){
            myFacebookLogin();
        });
    });

</script>
```

Comment: I encounter the same issue with [Parse platform](http://blog.parse.com/announcements/javascript-sdk-now-supports-facebook-login/).. please help

Comment: I found related question, tell me if it helps [Facebook user to Parse.com](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30881347/facebook-user-to-parse-com)

Comment: Or you can try use [parse-facebook-user-session](https://github.com/ParsePlatform/parse-facebook-user-session) as a middleware

Comment: As @NaBr metioned [parse-facebook-user-session](https://github.com/ParsePlatform/parse-facebook-user-session), there is an example [Parse-Facebook-OAuth-login-example](https://github.com/ssk7833/Parse-Facebook-OAuth-login-example) to check.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There seems to be a bug with Parses session handling with facebook.

It might not be a solution, but it is a workaround for the meantime,

you can use `session become` with the facebook token you acquired should do

the trick