# Facebook with Parse can't Login Swift 2.0

Tags: ios, facebook, swift, parse-platform, facebook-login

My app uses ParseSDK for creating Users and I want to implement simple Facebook login button in my application but I couldn't. I tried many times with FacebookSDK and ParseSDK Guides. But I failed. Could you look my codes and please tell me whats wrong ?

```
import UIKit
import CoreLocation
import Parse
import FBSDKCoreKit
import FBSDKShareKit
import FBSDKLoginKit
import ParseFacebookUtilsV4

@UIApplicationMain
class AppDelegate: UIResponder, UIApplicationDelegate {

var window: UIWindow?
let locationManager = CLLocationManager()

func application(application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [NSObject: AnyObject]?) -> Bool {
    // Initialize Parse.
    Parse.enableLocalDatastore()
    Parse.setApplicationId(Constants.ParseAPIKey, clientKey: Constants.ParseClientKey)
    PFFacebookUtils.initializeFacebookWithApplicationLaunchOptions(launchOptions)

    return true
}

func applicationWillResignActive(application: UIApplication) {
    // Sent when the application is about to move from active to inactive state. This can occur for certain types of temporary interruptions (such as an incoming phone call or SMS message) or when the user quits the application and it begins the transition to the background state.
    // Use this method to pause ongoing tasks, disable timers, and throttle down OpenGL ES frame rates. Games should use this method to pause the game.
}

func applicationDidEnterBackground(application: UIApplication) {
    // Use this method to release shared resources, save user data, invalidate timers, and store enough application state information to restore your application to its current state in case it is terminated later.
    // If your application supports background execution, this method is called instead of applicationWillTerminate: when the user quits.
}

func applicationWillEnterForeground(application: UIApplication) {
    // Called as part of the transition from the background to the inactive state; here you can undo many of the changes made on entering the background.
}

func applicationDidBecomeActive(application: UIApplication) {
    // Restart any tasks that were paused (or not yet started) while the application was inactive. If the application was previously in the background, optionally refresh the user interface.
    FBSDKAppEvents.activateApp()
}

func applicationWillTerminate(application: UIApplication) {
    // Called when the application is about to terminate. Save data if appropriate. See also applicationDidEnterBackground:.
}

func application(application: UIApplication, openURL url: NSURL, sourceApplication: String?, annotation: AnyObject) -> Bool {
    return FBSDKApplicationDelegate.sharedInstance().application(application, openURL: url, sourceApplication: sourceApplication, annotation: annotation)
}
}
```

There are the SDK Files.
[image]

There is the info.plist.
[image]

There is my LoginButton TableView Controller.swift file.

```
    import UIKit
import Parse
import FBSDKCoreKit
import FBSDKShareKit
import FBSDKLoginKit
import ParseFacebookUtilsV4

class UserProfileTableViewController: UITableViewController {
@IBOutlet weak var statusLabel: UILabel!
@IBOutlet weak var usernameTextField: UITextField!
@IBOutlet weak var passwordTextField: UITextField!

var user: User? {
    if let currentUser = PFUser.currentUser() {
        return User(user: currentUser)
    }
    return nil
}

override func viewWillAppear(animated: Bool) {
    self.configureStatusLabel()
}

func configureStatusLabel() {
    if user != nil { // User Logged In !
        if let name = user?.name,
            let surname = user?.surname {
                statusLabel.text = "Welcome, \(name) \(surname)"
        }
    } else {
        self.statusLabel.text = "You are not logged in"
    }
}

func face() {
    let permissions = ["public_profile", "email", "user_friends"]

    PFFacebookUtils.logInInBackgroundWithReadPermissions(permissions) { (user: PFUser?, error: NSError?) -> Void in
        if error == nil {
            print(user)
        } else {
            print("fail")
        }
    }

}

@IBAction func loginWithFacebook() {
    face()
}

@IBAction func logoutButton() {
    PFUser.logOut()
    self.configureStatusLabel()
}
}
```

When I click the my Login with Facebook Button. Safari opens and connects to the facebook like this. [image]

When I tap the Tamam which mean is OK button in this page. It returns my application with this error:

```
        2015-09-15 14:06:49.975 VetMapp[2233:81246] 
+[PFUser logInWithAuthTypeInBackground:authData:]:
 unrecognized selector sent to class 0x109fd8470
    2015-09-15 14:06:49.980 VetMapp[2233:81246] 
[Error]: Caught "NSInvalidArgumentException" 
with reason "+[PFUser logInWithAuthTypeInBackground:authData:]: 
unrecognized selector sent to class 0x109fd8470":
    (
```

First of all thank your for reading this and I really appreciated help for solve this problem. Thank you !

Comment: You may find you answer for your question in the following link [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31766107/using-parses-facebook-login-api-results-in-current-user-null/32309621#32309621)

Comment: Your link is directing me JavaScript language question. Not iOS or Swift. Please check your link.

Answer (score 0):

For Swift 2.0, you have to "whitelist" FB servers. You have to make a few changes to the Info.plist file and all will be working again. If you are using pods, make sure you update them as well.
Follow this link to see what you need to add in the plist file:
https://developers.facebook.com/docs/ios/ios9